# Как правильно вывести табы из бд?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap4

У меня есть табы созданные с помощью bootstrap.
[image]
Я хочу что бы количество табов зависело от того сколько я добавил в бд. Я добавил таблицу в бд
с id и tabs то есть название таба.
[image]
У меня все табы выводятся только разметка теряется!
[image]

В function.php создаю подключение к бд и чтение из бд

```
<?php

include 'config/config.php';

$get_id = $_GET['id'];
$get_tabs = $_GET['tabs'];

//Read
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM x_tabs");
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

А в индексном файле создаю табы таким образом

```
<?php foreach ($result as $res) { ?>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="<?php echo $res->id; ?>" data-toggle="tab" href="#<?php echo $res->tabs; ?>" role="tab" aria-controls="<?php echo $res->tabs; ?>" aria-selected="true"><?php echo $res->tabs; ?></a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Правленый код

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
<?php foreach ($result as $res) { ?>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="<?= $res->id; ?>" data-toggle="tab" href="#<?= $res->tabs; ?>" role="tab" aria-controls="<?= $res->tabs; ?>" aria-selected="true"><?= $res->tabs; ?></a>
    </li><?php } ?>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
<?php foreach ($result as $res) { ?>
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="<?= $res->id; ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="<?= $res->tabs; ?>"><?= $res->tabs; ?></div>
  </li><?php } ?>
</div>
```

Результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 2 foreach'а надо: первый для li, второй для div.tab-pane

Comment: div.tab-pane я пока не вывожу вообще, проблема в том  что все табы криво выводятся

Comment: Конечно криво.. Вы дублируете ul + li, а надо только li

Comment: Я так понимаю происходит это из за того что у меня <a class="nav-link active" то есть все вкладки активные.

Answer (score 0):

Только `li` должны быть внутри foreach

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist"><?php 
  foreach ($result as $idx => $res) { ?>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link <?= $idx === 0 ? 'active' : ''?>" id="<?= $res->id; ?>" data-toggle="tab" href="#<?= $res->tabs; ?>" role="tab" aria-controls="<?= $res->tabs; ?>" aria-selected="true"><?= $res->tabs; ?></a>
    </li><?php 
  } ?>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Таким образом они не переключаются

Comment: Добавьте tab-pane тогда поговорить можно о переключении

Comment: добавил код в вопрос

Comment: Я так понимаю происходит это из за того что у меня <a class="nav-link active" то есть все вкладки активные

Comment: Возможно. Не знаю как данные вкладки работают. Обновил - теперь класс active добавляется только первому эл-ту

Comment: Последняя правка работает нормально только в содержимом таба выводит все значения

Comment: А у содержимого тоже есть класс active, похожая проблема на сами табы

Comment: да у содержимого тоже есть класс active

Comment: его можно выводить только для первого у обоих foreach'ах. Вот так: `class="nav-link <?= key($res) === 0 ? 'active' : ''?>"`, т.е. этот код -> `<?= key($res) === 0 ? 'active' : ''?>` отвечает за вывод active у первого эл-та цикла

Comment: Если я делаю только для li то нормально а если ещё и для tab-pane то вообще всё содержимое пропадает

Comment: проблема мне кажется в том что для вывода контента я не правильно использую цикл foreach

Comment: Вы правильно его используете.. Проверьте внимательно html разметку и атрибуты в tab-pane

Comment: Ну в контенте должно появляться по одному <?= $res->tabs; ?> А не все в каждому. ALL должен быть в ALL.  BTC должен быть в BTC. LTC в LTC

Comment: Удалите класс active show... Было ведь уже, проходили..

Comment: Когда удаляю то вообще пустой контент получается